# bash - function declaration like C?

Tags: c, bash, function

Is it possible to declare functions in bash like in C ? 
Functions can get quite big so i don't want to define them at the beginning of the script.
For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Variable definition
myVar='Hello World'

#function declaration       <-- is this possible if yes how ?
function greeting() {}     


#main code
greeting


#function definition
function greeting() {
   echo $myVar
}
```

Comment: No. There is no "pure" function declaration (without the definition, as in `C`) in `bash`.

Comment: bash is interpreted, so greeting has to be defined at the point it is executed.  A later definition would just replace the earlier one.